# Get last activated data after clicked on button by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the last data when clicked on button in a week but nothing good show up. I have a pagination bar on this format `< 1 2 3 4... >` and i need to get the data when user clicked on button in order to make server processing in ajax like this:

- Click on button {data number} it will be: page = {data number} and ajax must be: /getData/{page}
- Clicked on button 2 ajax will send: /getData/2
- Clicked on button 4 ajax will send: /getData/4

…but the jquery always return the activated data which is before I clicked on button, example: when I click on 2 and after that click on 4, jquery will alert I clicked on 2 and in next click on another button will alert 4. So it will get the last activated data BEFORE the activated class change to another button. This is code I used to get data from:

```
  var page = 1;
  function onActive(){
            page = $('.paginate_button.active>a').text();
            alert($('.paginate_button.active>a').data('dt-idx'));
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.paginate_button', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            onActive();
        });
```

The element in html like this:

```
<li class="paginate_button active"><a tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="3" aria-controls="staff" href="#">3</a></li>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
  var page = 1;
  function onActive(_cur){
            page = cur.text();//You should get the correct page number            
         //Do whatever you want with the page
        }

    $(document).on('click', '.paginate_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        onActive($(this));
    });
```

Comment: sorry now i have an another problem is javascript is synchronous call between functions so ajax is always call the last actived value button before clicked. now i am trying to find how to make non-sync in javascript

Comment: if you think your question in now irrelevant then you should delete/modify it. If you feel my answer has helped you kindly upvote.